# Python/Sage: Skip a specific combination in nested for-loop

Tags: math, nested-loops, sage

while writing a somewhat simple function in sage I encountered a Problem:

I want to skip a specific combination, the case where both variables are the same. In short i only need the Variable-Combinations AB, BC and CA.

```
for Ax in [A, B, C]:
     for Bx in [A, B, C]: 
         if Ax==Bx:
             continue??
         else: 
             do stuff
```

I have tried and tried whatever came to my mind, but it always had the same Error. The loop contains a system of Equations that won't work with two identical Variables.

Thanks in Advance for any help, it is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools as IT
for Ax, Bx in IT.combinations(['A','B','C'], 2):
    print(Ax, Bx)
```

yields

```
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'C')
```

Comment: That solved the Problem with the identical Variables, thank you very much!
Can it be though, that this doesn't work with Lists somehow? I get an List Index out of range Error but don't see the Problem.